# Height, Width & Resizable modal's parameters are been ignored inside my JQuery modal code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog

I have the following jQuery code to show a modal popup:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            
            $(function () {
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                $(document).on('click', 'button[data-modal]', function (e) {
                    $('#myModalContent').css({ "margin": "5px", "max-height": screen.height * .82, "max-width": screen.height * .82, "overflow-y": "auto" }).load($(this).attr("data-url"), function () {
                        $('#myModal').modal({
                            height: 1000,
                            width: 2200,
                            resizable: true,
                            keyboard: true,
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            draggable: true
                        }, 'show');
                       
                    });
                    return false;
                });


            });
          });
```

and the following HTML:-

```
 <div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
     <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div id='myModalContent'></div>
           </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

now the generated modal popup will not be resizable + will not have height = 1000 and width = 2200 as specified in the modal parameters ,, any advice why my height,width & resizable modal's parameters are been ignored?

Comment: Add px at the end of the value

Comment: @Arm144 i tried so `height: '1000px', width: '2200px'`.. but did not work either

Comment: Just overwrite the modal class with your custom styles. If the height and with are respect the screen use for example: height: calc(100vh*0.85);